# Replacing integers with randomly selected integers from a variable

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.7

So I have a a program that needs to generate a random set of numbers in a set format, i.g 000-00-0-0000. I have a variable called integers that has 0-9 and I need to be able to take a random selection of those integers and input them in the format, is there anyway to do this?
[Here is the code for referencing.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rjrpl.png)

Comment: What have you tried so far? Your image of code only shows variables initialized to some value. Also, please paste code as text in the in the question and not as an image.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One approach is to generate a random number of up to ten digits (`9999999999`), left pad that number with zeroes, then use `re.sub` to introduce hyphens where you want them:

```
import random
import re

nums = str(random.randint(1,9999999999)).zfill(10)
nums = re.sub(r'(\d{3})(\d{2})(\d)(\d{4})', '\\1-\\2-\\3-\\4', nums)
print(nums)
```

This printed (when I ran it):

```
099-27-4-9895
```

Answer (score 3):

Using `random` and `str.format`:

```
import random

'{}{}{}-{}{}-{}-{}{}{}{}'.format(*(random.randint(0, 9) for _ in range(10)))
```

Sample Output (differs for every execution)

```
'377-38-3-2187'
```

Or if you already have a set pool of `int`s:

```
ints = [0,1,2,3]
'{}{}{}-{}{}-{}-{}{}{}{}'.format(*(random.choice(ints) for _ in range(10)))
```

Sample Output:

```
'221-03-3-2110'
```